# Google Places API - search place name by cyrillic parameter

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, encoding, google-places-api, cyrillic

I am using Google Places API to send request for places around me and I set the 'name' parameter to filter by name of place.

The thing is it all works good for latin names, but I want to search for places written in my native language (using cyrillic characters) and when I do so it returns no results. I have tried using a function called encodeURI(string) in javascript but it did not help. Is it even possible to perform this kind of search ?

```
var request = {

location: new google.maps.LatLng(41.98806, 21.45944),
radius: 50000,
name: 'базен'
```

};

It works for 'bazen' but it doesn't work for 'базен' (name parameter).

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search perhaps?
"Optional parameters" - "language" — The language code, indicating in which language the results should be returned, if possible. See the list of supported languages and their codes. Note that we often update supported languages so this list may not be exhaustive.
I know it says results *returned* but I would imagine it also affects requests - have you tried setting it? Sorry I only do English so I can't test it. :(